# Oracle loop statement

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I need some advice on how to write a select / function that passes through each row of a table, runs a select result against the expected result, and then writes to the new table for each row id 1 or zero, depending on the test result

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there something you don't understand?

Comment: Please edit the question and show ALL the table definitions and expected output.  thanks.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the question, it is about dynamic SQL. Here's an example:

Table; I chose to store the result into the same table. If you have another one, it is easy to fix it - instead of `update`, you'll use `insert`.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number,
  3     name     varchar2(20),
  4     script   varchar2(200),
  5     result   number);

Table created.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, name, script) values (1, 'number of employees', 'select count(*) from emp');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name, script) values (2, 'highest salary'     , 'select max(sal) from emp');

1 row created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select id, name, script from test) loop
  5      execute immediate cur_r.script into l_cnt;
  6      update test set result = l_cnt where id = cur_r.id;
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME                 SCRIPT                             RESULT
---------- -------------------- ------------------------------ ----------
         1 number of employees  select count(*) from emp               14
         2 highest salary       select max(sal) from emp             5000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. I wrote this code to run my scripts and update the result field in the result table. I would always like to write a new line along with the date the script was run. For example on Monday with a result of 1, then on a Tuesday with a result of 0. This means that I will have 3 rows for Monday and 3 rows from Tuesday with the same id from the test table. Don't know how to edit it?

DECLARE

```
CURSOR c_wrk IS 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        name,
        script
    FROM 
        test
    ;  
    w_rersult number;
```

BEGIN

```
FOR r_wrk IN c_wrk
LOOP
   execute immediate r_wrk.script into w_rersult;

UPDATE 
            result
        SET 
            result = w_rersult
        WHERE 
            id = r_wrk.id;

END LOOP;
end;
```